# Ingress-controller-nginx leader election - Why?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Can anyone explain why there is a requirement for leader election when having an ingress-controller (nginx) deployment with multiple replica's?
Is there a sync going on between them?
What is actually synced?

I searched the documentation and found ... nothing
I know there is a configmap that holds the POD name of the leader but that's pretty much it.

I also see that a leader election is going on when starting the pod

```
I0828 16:08:39.500651       7 nginx.go:307] Starting NGINX process
I0828 16:08:39.500779       7 leaderelection.go:242] attempting to acquire leader lease ingresscontroller/ingress-controller-leader...
I0828 16:08:39.500890       7 nginx.go:327] Starting validation webhook on :8443 with keys /usr/local/certificates/cert /usr/local/certificates/key
I0828 16:08:39.503049       7 controller.go:141] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0828 16:08:39.504322       7 status.go:86] new leader elected: ingress-nginx-controller-xxxxxx-xxxx
I0828 16:08:39.728368       7 controller.go:157] Backend successfully reloaded.
I0828 16:08:39.728416       7 controller.go:166] Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second.
```

Can anyone provide some insights on why there is a requirement for a leader?

Thanks in advance!

Bregt

Comment: Have you found a answer to this? @Bregt Coenen

Answer (score 4):

Leader election, in simple words, is the mechanism that guarantees that only one instance of the nginx ingress controller is actively making decisions, while all the other instances are inactive, but ready to take leadership if something happens to the active one.

This is very similar in nature to the control plane components of Kubernetes such as kube-controller-manager or kube-scheduler.

The sync is the synchronization of the desired state from the rules defined in Ingress resource into the actual nginx configuration file.

There is no state sync between the nginx ingress controller pod replicas itself because each of the pods are capable of performing the  synchronization of desired state from the Ingress resources to an actual nginx configuration file when the pod starts up first-time and by keeping a continuous watch on Ingress and few other resource via APIs exposed by Kubernetes API server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I understand what leader election is, but I don't know what decisions are actually being made by the leader. Traffic is going to both ingress-nginx pods and both pods are able to handle my requests. So basically, they should be both stateless. What does this leader do which the other node doesn't?

Indeed, there is no state sync between both nodes because they both have all information they need.

Comment: I am having this same issue...k8s cluster works for weeks then it seems to randomly decide to elect a new leader from one of the inactive ingress controller pods ...it self-heals but causes 502 errors to my clients for a few minutes...can't figure out why @BregtCoenen

Comment: I had the same question about why this leader election is even needed. The pods are stateless, so I should be able to load balance traffic to them and whichever one responds is fine. I use a DaemonSet to make sure an ingress controller exists on every node.

It seems the reason that leader-election is even needed in the first place has to do with status reporting for Ingress, VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute resources
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/command-line-arguments/#-enable-leader-election

Answer (score 4):

excerpt from the [documents](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/command-line-arguments/):

> -enable-leader-election
> Enables Leader election to avoid multiple replicas of the controller reporting the status of Ingress,
> VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute resources – only one replica will
> report status. (default true)

Comment: Additional to this, I find that 98% of the traffic is going to the 'leader' pod.  Why is this so? (I would expect a 50% distribution between two pods)